# Remove a particular name inside an array

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "list": [{
      "name": "car",
      "status": "Good",
      "time": "2018-11-02T03:26:34.350Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Truck",
      "status": "Ok",
      "time": "2018-11-02T03:27:23.038Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bike",
      "status": "NEW",
      "time": "2018-11-02T13:08:49.175Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I remove just the car info from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use filter option to filter out car related values

```js
var obj = {"list":[ {"name":"car", "status":"Good", "time":"2018-11-02T03:26:34.350Z"}, {"name":"Truck", "status":"Ok", "time":"2018-11-02T03:27:23.038Z"}, {"name":"Bike", "status":"NEW", "time":"2018-11-02T13:08:49.175Z"} ]}

let result = {
  list: []
}
    
result.list.push(obj.list.filter(v => v.name !=='car'))
console.log(result)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MzmMQp

**Option 2:** without using filter as requested by OP

Use simple for loop to achieve same result

```js
var obj = {"list":[ {"name":"car", "status":"Good", "time":"2018-11-02T03:26:34.350Z"}, {"name":"Truck", "status":"Ok", "time":"2018-11-02T03:27:23.038Z"}, {"name":"Bike", "status":"NEW", "time":"2018-11-02T13:08:49.175Z"} ]}

let result = {
  list: []
}
    
 for(let i =0; i< obj.list.length; i++){
   if(obj.list[i].name !== 'car' ){
     result.list.push(obj.list[i])   
   }

 } 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is there any way that the result can be achieved without using filter

Comment: @Nick, use simple for loop , updated my answer

Comment: I tried to use that but i have this TypeError: Cannot call method "push" of undefined.

Comment: check variables names which could be causing issue , as my code works from snippet

Comment: Now i'm getting a new error TypeError: Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined any idea?

Comment: var value = JSON.stringify(json);
var count = json.data.serverlist.length;
System.debug(count)
var value = JSON.stringify(json.data)
 var result = {
  list:[]
}
for(var i =0; i< count; i++){
   if(value.list[i].name !== "car" ){
     result.list.push(value.list[i])   
   }

 } 
System.debug(result);

Comment: above code giving me an error

Comment: remove JSON.stringify for value and use var value = json.data and try

Comment: Sai  Thanks!!! It works

Comment: glad it worked ... mark my post as answer , if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
let yourArray = obj.list;


  let filteredArray = yourArray.filter(elem => elem.name !== "car");
```

Comment: You forgot to parse it.

Comment: Parse what @squeekyDave ? Op says they have an array not json

Comment: @charlietfl the data passed is obviously a JSON.

Comment: @squeekyDave that is not a given. Could be hard coded into variable, or already parsed such as using `fetch()` or `$.getJSON`. OP specifically asked about *"array"*

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean is not given? It is the only thing the OP has posted.

Comment: Added @squeekyDave

Comment: @filip can we do it without using filter option?

Comment: @Nick you mean to keep the old array with the filtered options without creating a new one? Why would you want that?

Comment: @filip was trying to remove one of the object in that...seems like having some issues when using filter and I tried using push it’s not working...please give me any other way of solving this issue

Comment: @Nick still don't know what you are trying to achieve